Trouble Running Echidna on a Contract Requiring Constructor Argument
I'm encountering an issue while trying to run Echidna on a smart contract that requires a constructor argument. Despite several attempts, I haven't been able to provide the argument successfully.
Here's what I've tried so far:

Using the --args option with the argument:

echidna echidna_tests.sol --contract EchidnaSolution --args "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001"


However, I received an error stating "Invalid option --args".

Using the --solc-args option with the argument:

echidna echidna_tests.sol --contract EchidnaSolution --solc-args "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001"


This resulted in a compilation error with the message "Invalid solc compilation Error: unrecognised option '--0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001'".
I would appreciate any guidance on how to properly provide the constructor argument when running Echidna on a contract. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

From what I gather, Echidna doesn't support constructor arguments and you can read more about it in an issue discussion Handling constructor arguments.
But what it basically sums up to is that it's your job to handle the setup as the arguments are usually some implementation specific information known to the developers. Few offered options are:

Write a proxy contract which has no constructor arguments
Record the setup using Etheno End-to-End Testing with Echidna

There were mentions of a possible feature to be added in configuration (to provide constructor arguments), but so far didn't find evidence that it was done.
I'm pretty new to Echidna and the discussion quoted here is quite old, but so far these are the only answers I found so far. The crytic/building-secure-contracts has a lot of information on writing tests with Echidna and I recommend looking into it - it answered most of my questions. Good Luck!
If you are having trouble running the Etheno and recording the deployment - a very good example is set in their workshop part6 and it has a youtube video explaining the setup step by step.
